# Google Maps can't get my location

Tags: google-maps

This seemed to just start happening recently but for some reason Google Maps can't get my location (just have a gray dot).  If I go into Settings -> Location and choose High accuracy or Device only then I will just get the gray dot.  If I change it to Battery saving I can get the blue dot but it's obviously not as accurate so I'd like it to use GPS.  At first I thought there was a problem with GPS with my phone so I downloaded a couple of GPS status apps and they were all able to get GPS signal immediately (even with poor conditions; e.g., indoors).  If I go to maps.google.com in my browser on my phone (either Chrome or Firefox) I get a blue dot.  I've also downloaded Waze and HERE Maps and they can get my location without problem.

In Google Maps app I can tap on the gray dot and I get a message saying it can't connect to Maps and I should try again in a few minutes.  There is also an option to report blue dot issues.  This has been happening for a couple weeks now and it's really frustrating as I use Google Maps all the time.

I was thinking that maybe there was some issue with Google Maps and Google Play services but I double checked and I have the latest versions of both (I'm on a stock non-rooted Nexus 5x).  Is it possible there is a bug in Google Maps that I seem to be the only one experiencing?  Any help narrowing this down would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How long are you waiting for the location fix with the settings high accuracy or device only? If your other applications are using GPS only and getting a fix immediately indoors, this is probably not a new location fix, but a stored value.

Comment: I've waited quite a while.  At one point even let it sit for 30 minutes.  The other applications indicate they have live connections with multiple GPS satellites.

Comment: Exactly the same behavior, I detected this problem on my phone just yesterday. Several months ago I used Google Maps regularly with no problems. Maybe it has broken with some installed update.

Comment: Try installing GPS Status & Toolbox from the play store, no special permissions, it will tell you if your GPS is functioning correctly. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2

Comment: @acejavelin -- That's one of the GPS apps that I tried.  It shows GPS working just fine.  It seems to be an issue specific to Google Maps.

Comment: @JeffJones I assume you have gone to `Settings-Apps-Maps-Permissions` and verified that Location is enabled?

Comment: @peter -- I guess I'm glad to hear that I'm not the only one with this issue.  Out of curiosity, what kind of phone do you have?

Comment: @acejavelin yes but thanks for checking on that.

Comment: Again, when setting location mode to battery saving it can lock on, but when using the other two modes it can't.  And other apps have no issue with getting my location (including those that directly use GPS).  So it seems to be a GPS issue specific to maps and the location permission isn't fine grained enough to only disallow GPS location.

Comment: @JeffJones Try turn off auto updates in Play Store and uninstall maps, it should revert to the stock version that came with the Nexus 5x, does it work? If not, try force closing then clearing data on the Maps application and reboot. If it does work, reinstall the latest version and test again.

Comment: @acejavelin Good idea.  I just tried it and it didn't fix the problem using the older version of Maps.  My guess is that there was an issue introduced in the latest Google Play Services that Google pushes out that only seems to effect Maps on a few phones I guess...

Comment: @JeffJones My phone is a Honor 3C. I use many softwares dependent on GPS (GPS Essentials, GPS Test, GPS Status, GPSLogger, MapFactor Navigator, even Google Maps in Chrome) and they all work well, just Google Maps and one another similar software, Czech Mapy.cz do not. The dot is grey in both softwares. I have noticed that sometimes it turns to blue, but only for a moment, less than a second or so. Peter.

Comment: @peter ah that is exactly what I see too.  Sometimes for a split second it turns blue.  This morning it was even blue for several seconds but then returned to the gray dot.  I also notice that when I switch to another app and then back to Maps it turns blue for a split second.  I think that something is not quite right in Play Services.

Comment: I have version 9.2.56 of Google Play Services for whatever that is worth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem; fixing it was as simple as enabling automatic date and time and automatic time zone.  Not sure what program turned those off but correcting that make the problem go away. (When I turn them off, the problem re-occurs.)

Comment: I was sure this was already enabled so I almost dismissed your answer.  But I double checked anyways and sure enough it wasn't enabled (like you, I have no idea why it was turned off).  Turning it on fixed it!  You may want to add a comment to that Google forum post that talks about this issue.  That might assist people there and hopefully get Google's attention to fix this (this is clearly a bug in Google Maps and/or Play Services).

Answer (score 3):

Date and time. ....

Go to your device settings, Date and time. Check the automatic setting is on. If your device doesn't have auto setting for date and time, ensure your time is as accurate as possible. Should pop the blue dot up.

The Satellite connections seem to use this to assist your gps location. Without it, your position cannot be calculated and this will hamper route finding.

A recent update may have thrown this automatic date and time setting off. Curse 'em!