# "Searching for GPS" in Google Maps after update

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, gps, google-maps

I have been using Google Maps on the same phone (LG G4, android 6.0) for about 2 years now. Now suddenly after a Google Maps update the phone has GPS issues.
It can find where I am and my direction (before I input any destination) but when navigation starts, every 5 seconds or so I get a "Searching for GPS" message and it can't find where I am.
Needless to say that this has made the app useless as I cannot navigate anywhere.

If I use other GPS navigation apps such as HereWeGo everything works perfectly so a GPS harware issue is not the case.

I also waited for a new update to come, hoping that it might fix the issue, but the issue persists. I have also deleted tha app's cache and also deleted and reinstalled the app. Still nothing..

What happened with that update, and how can I fix that??

UPDATE: The problem might me a hardware issue as it started doing it on Waze and HereWeGO.

Comment: I am reading in google store comments on the app that a lot of people seem to have a similar issue but I still haven't found any solution for this.

Comment: Try [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/155082/213388).

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar Thanks for your suggestion. I checked and automatic date and time was turned on so it's not that.

Comment: Sorry mate as you've already tried deleting caches and reinstalling so nothing on that. This leaves an option to downgrade the app.

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar I will try that but first I will install a GPS app (like GPS toolbox) to reset GPS data. Might work!

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following troubleshooting steps to resolve the GPS issue:

1. **Setting location to high accuracy**

On your phone or tablet, open the Settings app Settings .

- Tap Location.
- At the top, switch location on.
- Tap Mode and then High accuracy.

---

2. **Get a GPS lock and alternative NTP server**

   - try getting a tool e.g [TopNTP 1.1](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2198319) which is highly recommended d to quickly lock the GPS position or even try calibrating using different  GPS configuration profiles and choose the best one.

---

3. **Using an alternative location provider**

   - You can make use of other alternative location providers e.g Unified NLP that uses alternative location backends such as GSM location backend or Wifi location service

Credits

https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2198319

Comment: I tried everything. I'm starting to believe that this might actually be a hardware issue because it now started to do this in other apps as well. It can find my location very quickly but It can't navigate without losing signal every 5-10 seconds.

Comment: Perhaps that could be the reason, try sending the device to a service center

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Cat S40 Android 5.1 and I found a solution for this exact problem (when I did this solution, I did not lose personal data, and my contacts and pictures, etc. were not deleted).

I went to Settings > Apps > Google Play Services and deleted Cache. Then, on the same screen, click on Manage space button > click on the last button to erase all data, then reboot your phone and install all Google related updates. Make sure to re-sign in for Google backup (for me, after I rebooted the phone, it gave me a warning that I have to set the backup).